# MYSQL select most recent for key

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the most recent `id` for every `company_id` (as defined by the timestamp), I tried the below but it's multiple rows per `company_id`...

```
SELECT id, MAX(created_timestamp), company_id
FROM company_status
WHERE active = 1
GROUP BY company_id, id
```

I can't do the `GROUB BY` statement without `id` because I get this error: `Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'lastone.company_status.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: hmm I think replacing `id` with `MAX(id)` will do the job :), then just group by `company_id`

Comment: @niceman Isn't that assuming `id` is sequential or in order?

Comment: You shouldn't have `id` in the `GROUP BY`, because then you get a different row for every ID.

Comment: @Abdul yes that's true, aren't most `id`s like that ?

Comment: @niceman sorry, missed out the `MAX()`, the issue is that it's not sequential so can't use `MAX(id)`...

Comment: @Barmar without `GROUP BY ..., id` I get: `Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'lastone.company_status.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: @Barmar please can you unmark this as a duplicate, the answer you pointed to doesn't help me. Thanks

Comment: The second query in the first answer should work for you.

Comment: If that doesn't work, you need to clarify this question to explain why. Show some sample data, the result you want, and the query you tried. It would be best if you included a link to sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: If you're still struggling, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - but I strongly suspect that Barmar's link nails it.